# Full width background in Flexbox navigation

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a `nav` element with an unordered list and several items. I am using Flexbox to ensure sufficient width between the items and account for Media Queries. However, My background-color property isn't spanning the entire width/height of the navbar. Do I need to set these properties on a different element?

```
nav {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  & ul {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    & li {
      flex-grow: 1;
      flex-shrink: 1 auto;
      flex-basis: 100%;
    }
    & li a {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
  }
}

<nav> 
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/1">First</a></li>
    <li><a href="/2">Second</a></li>
    <li><a href="/3">Third</a></li>
  <ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Looks fine to me https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/jwyNdJ

Comment: Did you forget to zero out the default margins & padding? Also `width:100%` isn't necessary on a `ul` as it's a block level element.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Paulie_D We have a winner. Tl;dr Resets are a thing. I would love to ask somebody who is deeper into how these kinds of CSS decisions get made why key value like this are not zeroed out by default...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st. Close your ul with `</ul>`

2nd. Are you talking about the margin at left and right? By default, body have an 8px margin.

If you add this will remove it:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Also, I compiled your SASS to CSS just showing the example here.

#### The following could be really helpful to understand the default CSS value for each HTML elements.

> ### Default CSS Values for HTML Elements
>
> https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1 auto;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/1">First</a></li>
    <li><a href="/2">Second</a></li>
    <li><a href="/3">Third</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Yeah, that should do it, as @Paulie_D also indicated.

Comment: @Chris Cool, also this could be really helpful =D https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp